# Как менять урл при переключении табов? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть одностраничный лендинг, без роутинга на реакте. При переключении табом меняются блоки. Как сделать так,чтобы при переключении табов менялся и `url` лендинга. По типу

```
https://url#1 . https://url#2
```

При открытии первой ссылки попадаем на страницу с табом 1 и блоками, при открытии второй - с табом 2

Comment: jquery можно использовать?

Comment: Оберните табы в атрибут <a>: <a href="#tab1"></a> При клике ссылки будут меняться. [Пример тут](https://codepen.io/andreasmcdermott/pen/dObbeE).     Перед проверкой удалите в JS строку №22 с кодом    "e.preventDefault()"  
    https://ibb.co/iNcNNm  Если это то что вам нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если сайт без роутинга, то я бы использовал просто windows.location.hash для этих целей

При заходе на сайт проверял:

```
const tab = location.hash;
switch (tab) {
  case '1':
  // ......
}
```

А при клике на таб соответственно

```
location.hash = tabNumber;
```